# SQL Reporting Services: Finding the folder a report is in

Tags: c#, .net, sql, reporting-services

If I have the report name how can I programmatically get the name of the project/folder the report is in?

So for example if I have a report like so

```
http://server/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/ReportProject1/ReportName
```

Given `ReportName` how can I figure out that the report is in the folder `ReportProject1`?

So I guess is there a function where I can pass int he report name and get it's details or else query the report server for a list of its report folders and I can loop through these and check some how that the report is inside?

Answer (score 3):

The data is in the catalog table in the reporting services database. So a query like

```
Select Path, Name 
From reportserver.dbo.catalog 
Where name = 'ReportProject1'
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use the reporting service api, you can create a custom app that connects to your report server using the reporting server web service. This will provide you with loads of information to query your install.

Check out [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155076(SQL.90)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155076(SQL.90).aspx).aspx for more info